Not able to mount AWS EFS file system on a task running a container
I am having trouble mounting an AWS EFS file system on a task running a container. Specifically, I would like to mount the EFS file system at the task level without mounting it directly inside the EC2 instance.
When I try to mount the file system inside the container, I get the following error:
mount: /efs: permission denied.
dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

I have attached the policies such as 'AmazonElasticFileSystemFullAccess' , 'AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy', etc., to the 'ecsTaskExecutionRole' role which is assigned to the task definition. I am able to mount the file system on ec2 instance which has the same permissions as to task, but I cannot mount the file system on task container.
If I add the mount volume and mount points inside the task definition, my file system is getting mounted inside the ec2 instance as well.  My requirement is to create a separate file system for each task container. The security group associated with the task/EFS has all traffic open for inbound and outbound.
Can anyone help me understand why I am encountering this permission issue and how I can mount the EFS file system directly inside the container? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
